# javascript, assign month and year to object

Tags: javascript

I need to make key value pair of month and year.

the result should be

```
options:[ {key: "May 2020"}, {key:"June 2020"}, {key:"July 2020"}....... , {key:"November 2020"}]
```

I need to show  above JSON for 6 months from now. For example:-  Now its April month so I need to show from May 2020 to November 2020

For getting the future 6 months month and year, I wrote the method below but I am getting confused how to show them in JSON

```
 const d = new Date();

    const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];


    year = d.getFullYear();
    let arr = [];
    for(let i = 1 ; i < 7 ; i++){
      let s = d.getMonth();
     let l = s + i;
     let key =  monthNames[l] + " " + year ;
      arr.push(key);
    }

    console.log(arr);
```

Need to show in a object key format. I am getting all the values in arr

Comment: @Phil yes, corrected it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```js
const today = new Date();
let currentMonth = today.getMonth();
let currentYear = today.getFullYear();
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];


let array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  currentMonth++;
  if (currentMonth > 11) {
    currentMonth %= 12;
    currentYear += 1;
  }
  array.push({
    key: `${monthNames[currentMonth]} ${currentYear}`
  });
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/flowtron/d3pnaL7f/5/

The core line for your code is probably:

```
monthNames[ monthIndex % 12 ] +" "+ year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const options = [];
        const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

        function retKey(month, year){
            let key = month + " " + year;
            return {key};
        }

        let today = new Date();

        for(let i=1; i<=6; i++){
            let tmp = new Date();
            let month, year;

            tmp.setMonth(today.getMonth()+i);

            month = monthNames[tmp.getMonth()].substring(0,3);
            year = tmp.getFullYear();

            options.push(retKey(month,year));

        }
        console.log(options);
```

Output:

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {key: "May 2020"}
1: {key: "Jun 2020"}
2: {key: "Jul 2020"}
3: {key: "Aug 2020"}
4: {key: "Sep 2020"}
5: {key: "Oct 2020"}
```